# Web page loading issues in Brave browser

Tags: websites, brave

I've been having some issues with loading web pages in Brave browser (on Ubuntu 20.04) for the past month. I believe the issue seemingly started after running an automatic update. The issues include: text or images go missing when I scroll, the content is repeated, parts of other pages in other open tabs are displayed.

Some examples:

Repeated text and items from other tabs.
[image]

When the page is loaded:
[image]

When I scroll down, video is displayed but text diappears.
[image]

Additional info:
I installed from PPA, using the [instructions on Brave's official page](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux). I have tried loading the same weg pages in Chrome, Firefox, and Chromium without issues, so it is seemingly Brave-specific.

Comment: I installed from PPA, using the [instructions on Brave's official page](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux).

Comment: From a quick scan of the instructions it looks like it uses `stable` as the release name (so eoan/focal won't matter), you could try a `sudo apt install --reinstall..` to re-install the program, esp. given the comment made below (that it started after change from *eoan* to *focal*).

Comment: I have to correct my previous statement regarding the issue starting with dist upgrade. It was later than this, and I believe it started after running an automatic update. I've tried reinstalling Brave without any luck.